# FadeIn using TweenJS

Tags: fadein, tween.js

I am trying to create a circle, for example, appear using something like `FadeIn` but in `TweenJS` library.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
    var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");
    var circle1 = new createjs.Shape(); 
    var x =circle1.graphics;
    x.setStrokeStyle(0.14, 'round', 'round');
    x.beginStroke(('#000000'));
    circle1.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0,10);
    x.endStroke();
    x.endFill();

    circle1.x = 250;
    circle1.y = 250;

    stage.addChild(circle1);
      circle1.addEventListener("tick", function(){
 createjs.Tween.get(circle1).to({alpha: 1,visible:true},1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not put the tweenJs inside de event Tick, because they will fire every tick.

I made an example: https://jsfiddle.net/nywsy1pp/

```
var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");

createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

var circle = new createjs.Shape(
    new createjs.Graphics().f("#f00").dc(0,0,100)
).set({x:100,y:100});
circle.alpha = 0;
stage.addChild(circle);

createjs.Tween.get(circle).to({alpha: 1},5000);

function tick() { 
    stage.update();
}
```